# MySQL is always taking 200% - 300% CPU during day time. Normal or bad?

Tags: mysql

MySQL daemon is always taking 200% - 300% CPU during day time. Normal or bad?
( Website has a concurrent connections 200 about but it's running Drupal without reverse proxy with many many writes operation with MySQL )

Comment: I don't believe your server can deliver more than 100% cpu-time to any given process.

Comment: Bad, of course. It should be network-bound when it's doing anything, and 0% CPU the rest of the time. It seems buggy to me as at 0.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this depends on mainly your available CPU and I/O power. If you have a lot of it, then this is no problem.

Instead of just looking at the used CPU, I would suggest to have a look at iowait. This is when processes are waiting for I/O to finish their tasks - e.g. the database waiting for the hard drives to write files on disk.

Comment: How to check iowait? I used vmstat, it's 7. I don't know if it's high or low